# Can I change my username?

Tags: discussion, user-profile

How I can change my username? As you can see my name <s>is</s> was *The Piano Man* because I started out in music stack exchange. Now I am in different communities, and I think it's funny to have someone named "The Piano Man" asking about Minecraft or stuff about Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your profile, click 'Edit Profile', then change your display name to whatever you wish.

Comment: Is this a joke? I thought I was the first one to answered this question (even though it was in the comment section) but now my comment gets deleted and now this? @TimmyJim are you serious?

Comment: @Skye-AT I'm not really seeing the issue here? Comments aren't meant to be used for answers, but once this answer was posted, your comment became redundant.  I also edited out the fluff since it's not necessary.

Comment: @TimmyJim I would say it's a bit rude to do so but if that's your stance then fine. The reason I've wrote in comment section is that because I thought it was going to be closed (since it was firstly posted on main arquade). Anyway, nevermind.

Comment: @Skye-AT I can't help what other users do, but there is nothing wrong with them posting an answer, even if (at the time) it was pretty much a copy and paste of your comment.  The user already posted the answer when the question was still on the main site.  The migration to Meta brought over their answer, which is technically correct and fine.  Ordinarily, most people would probably give way to someone who helped via comments first, but that didn't seem to happen here, but its only a meta question, so there isn't really much at stake/much to gain.

Comment: I also know that some people will take comments and post them as Wiki answers so not to steal credit (on the main site at least). [Example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/398389/163757) (though in the case of an edit rather than a comment)

Comment: @TimmyJim Yeah, `but its only a meta question` that's why I've said "nevermind". I've went a bit harsh, sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Everyone is so polite!